# Only allow call of PHP when user is redirected from a certain page?

Tags: php, redirect

Im working on a website where I need to implement Paypal Payment.

I currently have let's say payment.php. I only want this file to be accessed when It's called by Paypal. In Paypal, you can assign the redirect link once the purchase is successful. In this case, I want it to be redirected to 'https://www.mywebsite.com/payment.php' but I only want this link to be accessed if it's called by Paypal. In my other pages, I use session to prevent access. Any idea how I can implement this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to restrict. When PayPal calls your endpoint `payment.php`, you're supposed to validate it with a API call back to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should usually do the trick:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

But as @DavidChen pointed out, if you are using some payment information, you need to check an endpoint and validate the request.

Answer (score 0):

Use Paypal IPN:

Allow only POST, and implement the callback validation described in the IPN documentation.

https://github.com/dineshghule321/ipn-code-samples

[Check The Github Link :](https://github.com/dineshghule321/ipn-code-samples)

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/
[Paypal IPN Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/)